# Java turtle project

Tags: java

```
private void executeCommandsFromFile(String filename) {
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    processCommand(line);
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
                System.out.println("Commands executed from file: " + filename);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found: " + filename);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error reading file: " + filename);
            }
        }

public void processCommand(String command)              
        {
            
            if (command.equals("save")) {
                saveCommandsToFile("commands.txt");
            }
            else if (command.equals("load")) {
                executeCommandsFromFile("commands.txt");
            }
```

hey guys I am doing my java turtle project
I'm trying to load my saved commands when the user types load in commands typed in my turtle programme however when I input load it runs and infinite loop of the saved commands over and over again what should I do to fix this problem in my executecommandsfile() method?

Comment: The command "load" would not be part of the commands you load and execute, right?

Comment: When you type 'load'seems it's recursively calling executeCommandsFromFile() -> processCommand() -> executeCommandsFromFile() continuously

Comment: Also please include the content of your commands.txt as well

Comment: The commands.txt get updated everytime I type a new command or reset it